# Is there a way for Jenkins to just save the files from a git repo to a local folder?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, jenkins

I have a git repository with php files and Jenkins running in Ubuntu 18.04 with an Apache web server running on that. All I want is for Jenkins to periodically take the php files from my repo and save them to home/var/www/html.  I have everything set up and the repository is connected and authenticated - I just don't know how to make Jenkins save the files from my repository to the specified local folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@mygitserver.example.com/myrepo.git master | tar -x
```

see also the same question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750182/git-how-to-archive-from-remote-repository-directly